# sum a List of Optional Integers

Tags: java

I am trying to achieve the Java equivalent of the below Scala code

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-combine-map-flatten-flatmap-scala-cookbook/

```
class FirstClass {

    static String a[] = new String[] { "1", "2", "three", "4", "one hundred seventy five" };
    static List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(a);

    public static Optional<Integer> toInt(String in) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(Integer.parseInt(in.trim()));
        } catch (Exception NumberFormatException) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Optional<Integer>> c = FirstClass.myList.stream().map(item -> toInt(item)).toList();
        int sum = c.stream().mapToInt(item -> item.orElse(0)).sum();
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
```

My question is can I do it like in Java 17 using flatMap ?

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: I didn't downvote. But you are asking if you can do it with `flatMap` so I would expect you to try using `flatMap` in your code to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java code will be almost the same.. if you want to use `flatMap` just use [flatMapToInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-). As a result you have to return [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), so just wrap `item.orElse` in `IntStream.of`

```
int sum = c.stream()
       .flatMapToInt(item -> IntStream.of(item.orElse(0)))
       .sum();
```

But this could be done using just `mapToInt` operation. Looks simpler

```
int sum = c.stream()
       .mapToInt(item -> item.orElse(0))
       .sum();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following (not the most efficient):

```
int sum = c.stream()
        .flatMap(Optional::stream)
        .mapToInt(i -> i)
        .sum();
```

Or this alternative:

```
int sum = c.stream()
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .mapToInt(Optional::get)
        .sum();
```

Or this:

```
int sum = c.stream()
        .mapToInt(i -> i.orElse(0))
        .sum();
```

Or introduce a new utility method to use in your project:

```
public final class Optionals {
  public static int toInt(Optional<Integer> opt) {
    return opt.orElse(0);
  }
}
```

and then:

```
int sum = c.stream()
        .mapToInt(Optionals::toInt)
        .sum();
```

Comment: Knittl I like the last one from your solution's but In my opinion Scala is still very elegant here i think no ?

Comment: @jhon.smith sure. But Java is not Scala and Scala is not Java.

Comment: @jhon.smith I have added a 4th option, maybe it is closer to what you are looking for? Except for the class prefix, it is identical to the Scala solution

Answer (score 3):

You may want to return `OptionalInt` instead of a `Optional` when converting to `int` and also use `flatMapToInt`.

```
public class Main {
    static String a[] = new String[]{"1", "2", "three", "4", "one hundred seventy five"};
    static List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(a);

    public static OptionalInt toInt(String in) {
        try {
            return OptionalInt.of(Integer.parseInt(in.trim()));
        } catch (Exception NumberFormatException) {
            return OptionalInt.empty();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = myList.stream().flatMapToInt(item -> toInt(item).stream()).sum();
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be what you had in mind.

```
List<OptionalInt> s = List.of(
        OptionalInt.of(1),
        OptionalInt.empty(),
        OptionalInt.of(2),
        OptionalInt.of(3),
        OptionalInt.empty(),
        OptionalInt.of(4),
        OptionalInt.of(5),
        OptionalInt.of(6));
```

The `empty` optionals are automatically filtered out

```
int sum = s.stream().flatMapToInt(OptionalInt::stream).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

Prints

```
21
```

If you have `Optional<Integer>` you can just do

```
int sum = s.stream().flatMap(Optional::stream).mapToInt(a->a).sum();
// or
int sum = s.stream().flatMap(Optional::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.summingInt(a->a));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) out the empty optionals by [testing for the presence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent()) of a payload. Then [sum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum()) as `int` primitives using an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).

```java
int result = 
    list
        .stream()                         // Make a stream of the `Optional< Integer >` objects in our list.
        .filter( Optional :: isPresent )  // Skip those items where the `Optional` is empty (no payload on-board). 
        .map( Optional :: get )           // Retrieve the payload from its `Optional` wrapper. Safe to call `Optional#get` as we know the payload is present after having filtered out the empty ones in line above.
        .mapToInt( Integer :: intValue )  // Returns an `IntStream`. 
        .sum()                            // `IntStream#sum` returns `int`. 
;
```

Make some sample data to run this.

```java
List< Optional< Integer > > list = new ArrayList<>() ;
list.add( Optional.empty() ) ;
list.add( Optional.of( 7 ) ) ;
list.add( Optional.of( 42 ) ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wsX4t3).

To me, “elegant” means easy to read, in a simple logical flow. Shorter is not always better.

Comment: Hmm Basil but i feel the Scala version is incredibly easy to read no ?

Comment: Why filter when `list.stream().flatMap(Optional::stream).`  ignores empty `Optionals` and extracts the values for  processing.

Comment: @WJS Different strokes for different folks. I find neither `flatMap` nor streaming a single Optional to be obvious. Clever, but not obvious. So my code here is what I would use in production. But upon rereading the Question, the various `flatMap` solutions make for better fitting Answers. Reading the OP’s comments made me think the goal was "elegant" or better, but the question specifically asks for `flatMap`. So those Answers get my up-votes.

Comment: @BasilBourque  I used to do a ton of Perl programming.  Forgotton most of the syntax.  But the mantra was "There's more than one way to do it."